# Concatenate or print list elements with a trailing comma in Python

Tags: python, string, list, join

I am having a list as :

```
>>> l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

if I use join statement,

```
>>> s = ', '.join(l)
```

will give me output as :

```
'1, 2, 3, 4'
```

But, what I have to do If I want output as :

```
'1, 2, 3, 4,'
```

(I know that I can use string concat but I want to know some better way)

.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

String concatenation is the best way:

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']  # original list
s = ', '.join(l) + ','
```

but you have other options also:

1. Mapping to comma-ended strings, then joining:

   ```
   l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']  # original list
   s = ' '.join(map(lambda x: '%s,' % x, l))
   ```
2. Appending empty string to the joined list (don't modify original `l` list!):

   ```
   l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']  # original list
   s = ', '.join(l + ['']).rstrip(' ')
   ```
3. Using string formatting in place of concatenation:

   ```
   l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']  # original list
   s = '%s,' % (', '.join(l))
   ```

Comment: You might want to change `l` to `s` for all options or vice-verse?

Comment: `map(lambda)` is ugly IMO. Use a generator expression instead: `'%s,' % x for x in l`

Answer (score 7):

If you are in Python 3, you could leverage the print built-in function:

```
print(*l, sep=', ', end=',')
```

- `*l` unpacks the list of elements to pass them as individual arguments to print
- `sep` is an optional argument that is set to in between elements printed from the elements, here I set it to `', '` with a space as you require
- `end` is an optional argument that will be pushed at the and of the resulting printed string. I set it to `','` without space to match your need

You can use it starting Python 2.6 by importing the print function

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

However going this way has several caveats:

- This is assuming you want to output the resulting string in stdout ; or you can redirect the output in a file with the `file` optional argument into a file
- if you are in Python 2, the `__future__` import can break you code compatibility so you would need to isolate your code in a separate module if the rest of your code is not compatible.

Long story short, either this method or the other proposed answers are a lot of efforts to try to avoid just adding a `+','` at the end of the `join` resulting string

Answer (score 5):

For `str.join()` to work, the elements contained in the iterable (i.e. a list here), must be strings themselves. If you want a trailing comma, just add an empty string to the end of your list.

**Edit**: To flesh it out a bit:

```
l = map(str, [1,2,3,4])
l.append('')
s = ','.join(l)
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWild - I was wondering why I kept getting a trailing comma in my code, and it turns out that was because the last entry in the array I had was the empty string. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To include the spaces you've shown, you need to have a space in the separator string:

```
s = ", ".join(l) + ","
```

Or make it [DRYer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
sep = ", "
s = (sep.join(l) + sep).rstrip()
```

In the latter, `rstrip()` is just used to remove the final trailing space (part of `sep`) since that's not in your desired output. It's not the cheapest way of doing this, but it's pretty clear.

Comment: @aix: I agree about the requirement.

Comment: @aix: not really. Imagine their separator is more complex than just a comma (maybe even an expression) and they don't want to repeat it twice or use an temporary variable. Makes perfectly sense to me.

Comment: @thg435: Well, in the OP's example the two separators *are not the same*. One is `", "` and the other is `","` (note the missing space). I therefore don't really see how your argument applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `','.join(l)` won't work at all since it requires the elements to be strings, which they are not.

You can fix that and add the trailing comma like so:

```
In [4]: ', '.join(map(str, l)) + ','
Out[4]: '1, 2, 3, 4,'
```

I think this is by far the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want concatenation, things could be hacky...

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> repr(l+[0])[1:-3] # or str
'1, 2, 3, 4,'
```

Answer (score 0):

This IDLE session is a good example of how to pull the list elements into a string with a trailing comma:

```
>>> l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> ' '.join(x+',' for x in l)
'1, 2, 3, 4,'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for? It works though.

l = [1,2,3,4]

for num in l:
  print(str(num), end=", ")